# Colocating mystery server

Tags: vmware-vsphere, colocation, vsphere-client

My employer has tasked me with bringing a server over to a local web hosting facility. The server has vsphere pre-installed with numerous virtual servers installed(5 servers, 3 linux, 2 windows). After bringing this server to the web host they have emailed me back with the following.

```
Gateway: 67.x.y.z
Netmask: 255.255.x.y
IP range: 67.x.y.156 - 67.x.y.158
```

So I would like to ask how do I administer the virtual servers installed on that machine. I tried to ssh the IPs in the range given but it timed out. Is there anything I can do with the information they have given me? Why would they give me the gateway or netmask?

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot just unplug a server and plug it into a colo providers network, turn it on and expect it to work.

You need to update all the IP Addresses, gateways and so on on those machines and expose them in the correct way.  And there might be a bit more to it than just changing each machines IP details.  These servers might be inter-related. i.e. they may talk to each other.  Do they all need public IP's?  Since you have no idea, neither do I.

Unfortunately, you don't seem to know what they are and what they do or how they are configured and how to go about figuring it out.  I don't want to sound rude, but I think you're out of your depth here.  Most sysadmin's would have a pretty good idea on how to proceed.  I suggest you call in an expert who knows what they are doing.  You should not have been given this task in the first place.